# How to get the name of the tags using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a sample html code as follows:

```
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="455">
<td class="searchResultsImage">
<a href="/pets/2-months-english-bulldog-puppy" title="English BullDog">
....
..
..
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="456">
<td class="searchResultsImage">
<a href="/pets/3-months-french-bulldog-puppy" title="French BullDog">
....
..
..
```

The HTML code goes on and I have succeeded to get the content from between the tags; but I need the tag titles/names. To be specific I need to make a list that goes on like 455, 456 etc. I searched stackoverflow to find examples below:

```
soup.body.find('tr')['data-id']
```

They don't work.

Comment: what means `don't work` ? Sid you get erorr or what ? Maybe you get `<tr>` which don't have `data-id` . And maybe if you use `find('td', {'data-id': True})` then you get element which have `data-id`

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `<tr>` with attribute `data-id=` and then search `<a>` inside the rows.

For example:

```
txt = '''
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="455">
<td class="searchResultsImage">
<a href="/pets/2-months-english-bulldog-puppy" title="English BullDog">
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="456">
<td class="searchResultsImage">
<a href="/pets/3-months-french-bulldog-puppy" title="French BullDog">
</td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.select('tr[data-id]'):
    print(tr['data-id'], tr.find('a')['title'])
```

Prints:

```
455 English BullDog
456 French BullDog
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe what means `"don't work"`.

Maybe you have other `<tr>` without `data-id` and using only `find('tr')` you get this element and when you try to get `['data-id']` then it can't find it.

But you can use `find('tr', {'data-id': True})` or `find_all('tr', {'data-id': True})` to get only elements which have `data-id`

In example I added `<tr>` without `data-id` as first element to shows that it can gives error.

```
text = '''
<tr></tr>
<tr data-id="455"></tr>
<tr data-id="456"></tr>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

#for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'data-id': True}):
#    print(tr['data-id'])

print("--- with {'data-id': True} ---")
print('html   :', soup.find('tr', {'data-id': True}))
print('data-id:', soup.find('tr', {'data-id': True})['data-id'])

print("--- without {'data-id': True} ---")
print('html   :', soup.find('tr'))
print('data-id:', soup.find('tr')['data-id'])
```

Result:

```
--- with {'data-id': True} ---
html   : <tr data-id="455"></tr>
data-id: 455
--- without {'data-id': True} ---
html   : <tr></tr>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyError: 'data-id'
```